# Additional directories with behat

Tags: behat, autoloader

I'm putting together automated testing with behat - and encountered an issue I can't seem to find a solution to.

My behat.yml has all the usual stuff; I got directories for features and boostrap - and it all works.

Now, I have a separate directory, which contains additional classes that I need during the test execution.  While I can, of course, use lots of `require`, I'm sure there's a better way to add a directory to the autoloader - yet I can't figure out how.

For example, I have the following directory structure:

```
test/
    features/
    bootstrap/
    lib/
    behat.yml
```

behat.yml contains this:

```
default:
  autoload: [%paths.base%/boostrap]
  suites:
    web:
      paths: [%paths.base%/features/web]
      contexts: [Web\LoginContext]
    api:
      paths: [%paths.base%/features/api]
      contexts: [Api\ApiContext]
```

Directory `lib` contains additional classes that I need to use in my tests.  How can I add `lib` directory to the autoloader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much struggle, I kind of figured it out.  I need to add this directory to my `composer.json` file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyNameSpace\\": "lib/"
    }
}
```

and then run `composer update`.